# Subtracting two numeric columns

Tags: linux, awk

I need to subtract column two from three. So, I ran the following code on Linux server `awk '$3 - $2' in.bed >out.bed`, the output file generated was identical to the input file. I can't understand why this command is not working! Can anyone help?

The in.bed was:

```
chr19   2255482 2259550
chr19   2270962 2272924
chr19   2326618 2327833
chr19   2329714 2333233
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you put it, `$3 - $2` is parsed as a condition: Those lines where `$3 - $2` is not zero are selected and printed (because printing the line unchanged is the default action).

You can do what you want like this:

```
awk '{ print $3 - $2 }' in.bed > out.bed
```

The `{}` signify that what is enclosed in them is an action, and because there is no attached condition, `{ print $3 - $2 }` is executed unconditionally for all lines.

Comment: in a nutshell before i was going to answer :Dl...+1

Comment: @RashedulIslam star this answer if this is what you are looking fo

Comment: @Xorg, I can't vote up the answer because I don't have 15 reputation. I accepted the answer by clicking the tick mark. I am not sure what you mean by 'star'. Can you help?

Comment: @RashedulIslam ..I +1 your question..hope you reach 15 rep!